# Can 'make' have 'having fluttered' as its objective complement?

Tags: complementation, present-participles, causative-make

Even though grammar books says ‘make’ don’t have present participle as its objective complement; this sentence “The potion makes the moths **having fluttered** and all dead” seems to be not ungrammatical. 
Because ‘having’ in this sentence is not a present participle but an auxiliary. Is the sentence grammatical or not?

Comment: Is there more to that sentence? It does not seem complete.

Comment: That's my own. I wanted to express the moths have fluttered a certain period and then all died. Then I need to adopt perfect tense: Now i'm wondering whether I can use the 'having.' In this case, 'having' is not a main verb, but a auxiliary, so it's very confusing.

Comment: If you want to keep the "having fluttered" phrase, you might try something like: The moths, having fluttered frantically all night after being given the potion [poison?], { were all dead by morning. / all died the next morning.}

Comment: NB: It's still a participle, just as in *to have fluttered* *to have* is still an infinitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this should be grammatical; but in fact,

- Participial perfect constructions like *having fluttered* are not employed as direct or predicate adjectives in English, although they can be employed as sentence adjuncts. It's just not idiomatic.

  > <sup>✲</sup>The having-fluttered moths ... *must be expressed as* The moths which have fluttered
  >    <sup>✲</sup>The moths are having fluttered ... *must be expressed as* The moths have fluttered.
- Likewise, non-finite perfect constructions like *to have fluttered* are not employed as complements of causatives like *make*, *cause*, and *bring about*.

  > <sup>✲</sup>I made the moths to have fluttered. ... *can only be expressed as* I made the moths flutter.
- Finally, although you can *maybe* effect a state of deadness with *cause* ...

  > <sup>?</sup>I caused the moths to be dead.

  ... the same expression won't wash with *make*:

  > <sup>✲</sup>I made the moths dead.

  Causative expressions with death as the outcome are expressed lexically:

  > I killed the moths.

---

<sup>✲</sup> marks an utterance as unacceptable
<sup>?</sup> marks an utterance as possibly unacceptable

Comment: But you can have the albeit somewhat stilted "I made the moths die", even if you can't have "I made them dead".

Comment: @Matt Indeed you can; but you usually don't. More to OP's point, you can't say "I made the moths to have died."

Comment: @StoneyB: But you *can* say "I made the moths have died." (It would require an unusual context, though, since it implies that the speaker was able to go back and change a past event. It might happen if the speaker is a journalist or novelist or something, and the "made" expresses depiction rather than ordinary causation.)

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not possible. The sentence should be:

> The potion makes the moths flutter and die.

This is grammatically correct. Whether it's semantically acceptable is another question, however. Moths and butterflies and other winged insects all [flutter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flutter) when they fly. Therefore, perhaps it's necessary to add a modifier, e.g.:

> The potion makes all (the) moths flutter {ferociously / fiercely / forcibly / frantically / furiously / heavily / intensely [CHOOSE ONE]} and die.  [**EDIT:** Added suggested, but, perhaps, optional "the" at snailplanes/s suggestion]

Comment: Surely *all the moths* rather than *the all moths*?

Comment: I watched the test in a TV program. And the moths fluttered all night frantically, and next morning they all died. How can you imply ‘they fluttered all night frantically before dying’ in your sentence?

Comment: @Listenever You just did! ... but as I keep telling my clients, The Language is your Lady, not your employee, and there are some things that She just doesn't want you to do; you have to do things Her way, not yours.

Comment: @snailplane: You're right, but I made it optional because I'm not really sure about the context. With the _the_, it's specific, but without it, it's general. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @StoneyB, If I made a brochure of your replies, these words would be the preface. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Listenever I mostly stole it from Robert Graves. But I have no doubt that somewhere along the line a Korean poet said the same thing about your language.

Comment: @BillFranke I'm sorry, my comment was about [an older revision](http://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/4146/1), and I'm afraid my meaning may have become unclear by the time you read it.  I only meant to point out a typo.  My apologies for any confusion!

Comment: @snailplane: I hadn't noticed that typo, so thank you for spotting it, and I hadn't noticed Matt's revision either (sorry, Matt). But when I read your comment, I looked at my second S and thought that your comment was a good one. No need to apologize. :-)